# Output of decodeURIComponent cannot be parsed by JSON.parse()?

Tags: javascript, json

Why doesn't the following work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

var str="{&quot;bmi&quot;:&quot;25.25&quot;}";

var unesc = decodeURIComponent(str);
document.write(unesc);

var obj = JSON.parse(unesc);
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p4c4q6q1/1/

Looks like JSON.parse() is not liking the output of decodeURIComponent() for some reason. If I manually replace the string reference with the actual string then JSON.parse() works.

Comment: The string is not URIEncoded, it is HTML Encoded, you've to decode it. **If you're using jQuery** [`$('<div />').html(str).text()`](https://jsfiddle.net/0wdkukLf/)

Comment: As checked your jsfiddle, it giving the output as `{"bmi":"25.25"}` what is the actual issue?

Comment: @Thennarasan You should see `{"bmi":"25.25"}` printed out twice instead of one time. If you check the javascript console you'll see an exception from `JSON.parse`.